# How to fix exec format error on 64-bit Linux?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86-64

I am learning x86_64 assembly. But I have run into the following problem:

I am assembling a program with `gcc -g -c exercise1.s -o exercise1.o` and linking it with `ld -g -o exercise1 exercise1.o -m elf_x86_64`

However when I try to run the program I get the following error: `bash: ./exercise1: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error`

Running `uname -a` I get `Linux lubuntu 4.15.0-20-generic #21-Ubuntu SMP Tue Apr 24 06:16:15 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux` and `arch` outputs `x86_64`.

`file` outputs `exercise1: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), corrupted program header size, with debug_info, not stripped`.

To me it seems that I am trying to run a 64-bit program on a 64-bit kernel on a 64-bit CPU. Why is it not working?

Comment: Works for me on Arch GNU/Linux using that `ld` command to link `gcc -g -c foo.s` output.  What's in your `.s`?  (Normally you don't need `-m elf_x86_64`, the default is already x86-64. 
 Does the a.out made by `gcc -static -nostdlib exercise.s` work?)

Comment: Wait a minute, `corrupted program header size`?? That's super weird.  Are you sure your hardware isn't failing, like bad RAM?  (Can you reproduce this if you run the same commands again?)  A working `ld` should never make an ELF executable with broken headers.  Maybe try `readelf -a` on it.

Comment: Regarding the output from `file`: [here's](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=882310) a guy getting similar output, and it seems like the Debian maintainers fixed this in August of 2018. OP's lubuntu (which I believe is derived from Debian) build appears to be from April 2018.

Comment: If the file really does not contain any program headers (see link in the comment of @Michael), this would mean that the object file did not contain any sections... Maybe the assembly file was empty?